# XML read same tag with different segment

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Below are the xml file

```
<maindata>
        <publication-reference>
          <document-id document-id-type="docdb">
            <country>US</country>
            <doc-number>9820394ASD</doc-number>
            <date>20111101</date>
          </document-id>
          <document-id document-id-type="docmain">
            <doc-number>9820394</doc-number>
            <date>20111101</date>
          </document-id>
        </publication-reference>
</maindata>
```

i want to extract the `<doc-number>`tag value under the type = "`docmain`" 
below is my java code, while executed its extract `9829394ASD` instead of `9820394`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath ="D:/bs.xml";
        File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("publication-reference");
            List<Biblio> docList = new ArrayList<Biblio>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                docList.add(getdoc(nodeList.item(i)));
            }

        } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static Biblio getdoc(Node node) {
           Biblio bib = new Biblio();
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element element = (Element) node;
            bib.setCountry(getTagValue("country",element));
            bib.setDocnumber(getTagValue("doc-number",element));
            bib.setDate(getTagValue("date",element));          
        }
        return bib;
    }
```

let me know how can we check the Type its docmain or doctype, should extract only if the type is docmain else should leave the element

added the getTagValue method

```
private static String getTagValue(String tag, Element element) {
        NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
        Node node = (Node) nodeList.item(0);
        return node.getNodeValue();
    }
```

Comment: Besides your problem, because you're trying to unmarshal a xml to a class, if you're using eclipse there is a tool called eclipselink moxy https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/ which is perfect for this kind of operations. It is way more straight forward, and I use this quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Change your method `getdoc()` so that it create only a `Biblio` object for 'docmain` types.

```
private static Biblio getdoc(Node node) {
  Biblio bib = null;
  if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element element = (Element) node;
    String type = element.getAttribute("document-id-type");
    if(type != null && type.equals("docmain")) {
      bib = new Biblio();
      bib.setCountry(getTagValue("country",element));
      bib.setDocnumber(getTagValue("doc-number",element));
      bib.setDate(getTagValue("date",element));          
    }
  }
  return bib;
}
```

Then in your main method you should only add to the list, if `getdoc()` result is not null:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
  Biblio biblio = getdoc(nodeList.item(i));
  if(biblio != null) {
    docList.add(biblio);
  }
}
```

**Update:**
Ok, this is horrible, sorry. You should really learn a little bit about XPath.
I try to rewrite this using XPath expressions.

First we need four XPath expressions. One to extract a node list with all `document-id` elements with type `docmain`.

The XPath expression for this is: `/maindata/publication-reference/document-id[@document-id-type='docmain']` (whole XML document in context).

Here the predicate in [] ensures, that only `document-id` elements with type `docmain` are extracted.

Then for each field in a `document-id` element (with `document-id` element as context):

- country: `country`
- docnumber: `doc-number`
- date: `date`

We use a static initializer for that:

```
private static XPathExpression xpathDocId;
private static XPathExpression xpathCountry;
private static XPathExpression xpathDocnumber;
private static XPathExpression xpathDate;

static {
  try {
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    // Context is the whole document. Find all document-id elements with type docmain
    xpathDocId = xpath.compile("/maindata/publication-reference/document-id[@document-id-type='docmain']");

    // Context is a document-id element. 
    xpathCountry = xpath.compile("country");
    xpathDocnumber = xpath.compile("doc-number");
    xpathDate = xpath.compile("date");
  } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Then we rewrite the method `getdoc`. This method now gets a `document-id` element as input and creates a `Biblio` instance out of it using XPath expressions:

```
private static Biblio getdoc(Node element) throws XPathExpressionException {
  Biblio biblio = new Biblio();
  biblio.setCountry((String) xpathCountry.evaluate(element, XPathConstants.STRING));
  biblio.setDocnumber((String) xpathDocnumber.evaluate(element, XPathConstants.STRING));
  biblio.setDate((String) xpathDate.evaluate(element, XPathConstants.STRING));
  return biblio;
}
```

Then in the `main()` method you use the XPath expression to extract only the needed elements:

```
  NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpathDocId.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
  List<Biblio> docList = new ArrayList<Biblio>();
  for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    docList.add(getdoc(nodeList.item(i)));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the Getdoc() method always getting empty value (string Type), so my output collection are empty

Comment: Can you provide the code for the method `getTagValue()`?

Comment: added the getTagValue() method in the question body

Answer (score 1):

The value could be retrieved with [following](http://xpathfiddle.net/1J17R9) XPath using the [DOM and XPath API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java).

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new File(...) );
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//document-id[@document-id-type=\"docmain\"]/doc-number/text()");
    String value = expr.evaluate(doc);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the Help, following are the code

```
String Number = xPath.compile("//publication-reference//document-id[@document-id-type=\"docmain\"]/doc-number").evaluate(xmlDocument);
```